# Are there any algorithms to check if a big number is a prime number?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

I want to check if a given number is a prime number. Are there other ways than brute-force? It should be fast and work with bigger numbers (>1.000.000).

Comment: Have you heard of [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Miller)? Or read the Wiki article [on primality testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)?

Comment: Looks good, i will try to create a code of this!

Comment: Also, $10^6$ is not a "big" number nowadays. Consider that you only have to check for divisibility for primes under $1,000$ to check if a number in the order of $10^6$ is prime.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Indeed, you could factor a number well over a million million by pure brute force in a flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your number is big enough (absurdly big), and you need a deterministic algorithm (unlikely), then your best bet is the [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), the first (only?) deterministic primality test proven to produce an answer in time polynomial in the number of digits.

Comment: Thanks, but your link to wikipedia goes to the mobile version.